# Create form popup Using lightbox popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating form popup using lightbox popup

Here is my code:

```
<div id="vendor-popup" style="display: none;background:white;">
    <div style="clear:both;padding:10px;">
        <div><h3><?php echo $this->__('Contact Form');?></h3></div>
    </div>
    <form id="contact_vendor" action="" method="post">
        <p>
            <label class="required" for="name"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Full Name');?></label>
            <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry" title="Name" id="name" name="name" value="">
        </p>
        <div class="buttons-set">
            <p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields');?></p>
            <input type="text" style="display:none !important;" value="" id="hideit" name="hideit">
            <button class="button" title="Submit" type="submit"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit');?></span></span></button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="popup-content-block"></div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newContactForm = new VarienForm('contact_vendor', true);
</script>
<button onclick="showPopUp();" class="button" type="button"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Contact To Vendor') ?></span></span></button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function showPopUp(){
        jQuery.fancybox.open('#vendor-popup',{
            width : 'auto',
            height: 'auto',
            openEffect  : 'elastic',
            closeEffect : 'elastic'
        });
    }
    //]]>
</script>
```

this show me proper popup but when i check in console form tag is not display any where how to solve this problem

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: in js fiddle its working

Comment: You have to insert html , css and jquery in jsfiddle. You cannot insert your 'php'('<?php .... ?>') inside that.